# BCM2835 datasheet addressing system

Tags: raspberry-pi, bare-metal

I've been interested in writing a kernel for my old Raspberry Pi for quite a while, and managed to make work some ARM assembly code I found on the famous "Baking Pi" course by the University of Cambridge. Since I know some ARM assembly I wanted to dive deeper in the datasheet, but found "it contains several errors" (although I also found is an errata corrige page), and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the following:

The first course lesson says that "the manual uses a different addressing system. An address listed as 0x7E200000 would be 0x20200000", and that would be the address of the GPIO interface.

What I don't get is: is there a correspondence between the two addresses? Can I use some sort of conversion to read from the datasheet?

Thanks :)

P.S. I tried to post this to the raspberry pi site but as far as I could notice it's not very active..

Comment: yes for the older part, the arm 11 whenever you see 0x7E000000 then just use 0x20000000 for the newer parts I think that is 0x3F000000.  The document is written I assume for the GPU address space and the arm address space is different (as shown in that doc).  If coming from the north my house is the third on the right.  but from the south it is the 7th on the left.  same house same street, different view.

Comment: No need to convert this in your code, but since this is part of history now and we know that they changed the address again so that the arm could have more ram no doubt, you may wish to do a base+offset thing in your defines.  And then ifdef the base based on which platform.  (or runtime it, it is your software design).

Comment: The bare metal forum is a rare case of being far superior than stackoverflow for this family of products.  Lots of very detailed technical knowledge.  This particular topic has been covered countless times, so normally might not get much attention.  and baking pi has bugs which have been covered countless times as well.  There are so many bare metal examples pinned on the forum to start from, arm11 (armv6), armv7 and armv8.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments! I'll check out the bare metal forum, I hope it helps :)

Comment: Again as far as the datasheet goes the 0x7E addresses you use as 0x20 on the old pi boards.  The newer arms were swapped in so the peripherals are the same just a different base address.  The pi folks chose to light up all the arms at once rather than let software turn the other three on (for the multicore ones) so there is example code in the links on the forum for code to "sort the cores" you need to basically park three of them in an infinite loop otherwise all four try to execute all the code linearly and that causes problems.  and you can use aarch32 or aarch64 (or both) with the newrones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasheet appears to be written from the addressing view of the GPU which is not the same view as the ARM. (sorta shown in the document).  The older pi chips with the ARM11 core the base address for peripherals in the ARM address space is 0x20000000 you ignore the 0x7E part and "translate" in your head to 0x20.  For newer chips used on the pi the ARM cores has been swapped out and likely to give more linear space for ram the ARM base address for peripherals is something like 0x3F000000 so when you see some 0x7Exxxxxx address you use 0x3Fxxxxxx address.

While it may not be active the raspberry pi bare metal forum is filled with folks with very detailed knowledge about these chips/boards as well as links to many good examples (better than baking pi by a long shot).  That forum is one of the cases of a resource far superior to stackoverflow.  At the same time this question has been asked countless times so may not warrant an answer, covered in the tutorials and examples pinned to the forum page.

Because of the availability, price, and that forum in particular this is a very good platform for learning bare metal and perhaps dabbling in writing an OS.  pi-zeros are still available and use the ARM11 and is the best starting point for this kind of work.  Moving on to the much more complicated cores once you get your feet wet.